# Unwind Segues are not calling "prepareForSegue" in my mother view

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

```
Mother View -> Child View (push)
```

When I perform a manual unwind segue back to the mother view, my mother view's "prepareForSegue" does not get hit.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        println(segue.identifier) //unwind segues don't print! 
}
@IBAction func unwindToTabBar(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prepareForSegue` for the unwind needs to be in the child viewController, because it is preparing for the return trip.  The `destinationViewController` in this case will be the mother viewController.